# NodeJS reponse.writeHead not there

Tags: node.js, http, web, header

I have been trying to follow a few node js tutorials but I cannot seem to do so as response.writeHead is not there..

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Is the above code I am trying to execute but I get the warning "Unresolved function or method writeHead()" - i've looked around but cant get any further, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using IntelliJ IDEA and the warning has nothing to do with node.js but IDE itself. Check your settings

`IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> JavaScript -> Libraries 
-> [Ensure 'Node.js Globals' is checked]`

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ so can't really help you setting that up, but if you just want to try your code then open terminal and run `node <your-script-name>.js`

Comment: @Ashton Ok i just check jetbrains.com and it says that node.js is *Supported only in Ultimate Edition* https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: I am using JetBrains Webstorm, not IntelliJ :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem in their latest WebStorm/PhpStorm IDE versions (as at Feb 2017), you can go to `File`/`Settings`/`Languages & Frameworks`/`Node.js and NPM` and then under `Coding Assistance` subsection, click on the `Enable` option.

[image]

[image]